# Excel VBA Make Function Volatile based on User selected Style Options

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a UDF that validates against User defined style options, specifically in this circumstance, for `ListObjects`, but I was hoping for an universal answer.

Take an example table: Table1

My UDF is as follows, for demonstration purposes we are in cell A2:

```
=TableHeaderExists("Table1")
```

The function returns a result:

```
Public Function TableHeaderExists(table_name As String) As Boolean

  TableHeaderExists = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(table_name).ShowHeaders

End Function
```

A2 now returns a result. But it does not recalculate when the condition changes by user unchecking the check box in the 'Design Tab'.

So I added `Application.Volatile` to the Function.

A2 still does not recalculate. So I removed `Application.Volatile` and added `ActiveSheet.Calculate`

In this case it works for one change, and one change only.

What I did notice, is if I edit any data in the table, ANY data at all, those cells with the validation function are then recalculated, but not when Style Options are altered.

So I then tried to get a result by validating against a range for the header and that too works just like validating against 'ShowHeaders', only updates after body data is altered somehow, not appearance:

```
Public Function TableHeaderExists(table_name As String) As Boolean

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim hdrRng As Range

Application.Volatile

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(table_name)
Set hdrRng = tbl.HeaderRowRange

If Not hdrRng Is Nothing Then
 TableHeaderExists = True
Else
 TableHeaderExists = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that is not going to work:

UDFs only get calculated when:

- A calculation event is triggered and
- Either one of the parameters for the UDF gets dirtied  or the UDF is 
  flagged as volatile

Changing the check box in the design tab does not trigger a calculation so the UDF does not get calculated.

Comment: That makes sense the way you explain it. Can you help me understand why `Calculate` forces a recalculation then, but only once. Additionally why do checks and balances against a range object not produce desired results as well? I can understand the a checkbox not triggering, but when a range isn't there? I don't follow that

Comment: Don't know why adding .Calculate inside a UDF forces a recalc for you: it does not for me. Recalc does not get triggered by changes to the visual appearance of things.

Comment: Sorry. I've had work since our last conversation. I couldn't get it to replicate, but it still updates from the checkbox anytime the data body range values are altered so I think I'll make a 'hacky' workaround by inserting/deleting or just editing a cell in the range. Still not sure why my second example doesn't produce an outcome when it checks against a range. But thanks for the help